# Macro to Copy Cells from one Column to the Clipboard if Another Column Equals Value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large list of contacts and I want a macro that copies their email addresses, Column J, to the clipboard if they've been selected, ="a" in Column C.

The contact list is constantly edited with some being deleted and others added.  I've named the row above and below the data information for function reference which has been working well with my other macros.

```
Sub CopySelected()
Dim oData As New DataObject 
oData.SetText Text:=Empty 'Clear
oData.PutInClipboard
With Worksheets("Master")
    For Each Cell In Range(.Cells(.Range("BorderFirstRow").Row + 1, "C"), _
                .Cells(.Range("BorderLastRow").Row - 1, "C"))
        If Cell.Value = "a" Then

                .PutInClipboard
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

What do I need to do to have the macro copy the email address, Column J, if Column C="A"?

Comment: What is your goal after you have it in clipboard? Because it would be much easier to use `Range().Copy` to copy it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fictitious worksheet with fictitious data. Hope it is like yours:
[image]
 The code below gave no errors for me:

```
Sub CopyToClip()

Dim ClipB As New DataObject
Dim RangeToConsider As Range
Dim strAddresses As String

    ' set the range
    ' here just set the relevant range from the C column
        Set RangeToConsider = Range("E4:E7") ' in my case!
For Each cell In RangeToConsider
    If cell.Value = "a" Or cell.Value = "A" Then
        If Not (Trim(cell.Offset(0, -2).Value) = "") Then
           strAddresses = strAddresses & "; " & cell.Offset(0, -2).Value
        end if
    End If
Next
strAddresses = Mid(strAddresses, 2) ' delete the first semicolon
strAddresses = strAddresses & ";" ' add a semicolon at the end
strAddresses = Trim(strAddresses) ' delete spaces if any
Debug.Print strAddresses
ClipB.SetText strAddresses
ClipB.PutInClipboard
Debug.Print ClipB.GetText()
End Sub
```

So, after running the procedure, I am able to paste 'Name; AnotherName;'

Comment: Thank you Serhi and Peh.  After it is copied, we want to paste it into the To: Outlook field.

Comment: Serhii - I receive a compile error on the AllAddresses.PutInClipboard

Comment: nice! that makes it fairly easy; I believe the To: field is exactly separated with semicolons. Then you can try my method after a bit of cleaning up. I make final edit in 10 minutes

Comment: Yes, thank you.  Separated by semicolons or maybe commas.

Comment: Yes!  Thank you.  It does put about 50 semi-colons behind the list.  Haven't tried sending an email to see if it matters but do you happen to know the cause?  Thank you again!

Comment: @Neuner if you 're getting like ;;;;;;; at the end then you must have empty cells where Email addresses should be. You can write a procedure to either control for the contents of the cell or clean up the addresses at the end. see my edit above

Comment: I didn't think of that.  You are correct.  Thank you once again, it is much appreciated!